# End thread by ID

Tags: c#

I am trying to handle some threads. I saw it is possible to get a unique ID from the thread or to set an thread-name. But how it is possible to end / abort a thread by his ID? I don't belive .NET has his own ability to do this right? Maybe Win32-API?

Comment: Ahem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx

Comment: Thanks, how can i use it? What will it except? An ID? A name? (Sorry)

Comment: Why do you want to terminate a thread in the first place? That's problematic in the managed world, and total disaster in the unmanaged world.

Comment: @CodesInChaos e.g. because the code was written bearing in mind that there have to be an analog to Unix signals? And now the code is ready, and C# turned out to have no an analog, which leads to either rewriting a bunch of code, either making a hack with Abort.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of all the operating system threads (represented by [the `ProcessThread` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.aspx)) of the current process using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads`, but you can't abort them this way.

On the other hand, you can abort managed threads (represented by [the `Thread` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)), but there doesn't seem to be a way to list all the threads (except maybe using the unmanaged debugging API).

What you could do it to store all the threads you create in a list and when you want to abort one of them, use the list to find it.

BUT aborting threads is a really bad thing to do and you shouldn't do it, if at all possible. There is probably better way, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast response. You are right but it is for my server-management and sometimes i need to kick or ban a user. So if i got the Thread-ID i can just use Abort(ThreadID) to end it? I am not sure if i know excatly how to kill the thread if i got his ID?

Comment: @Milian, I don't understand why do you need to abort thread to kick user. And read my answer again, there is no `Abort(ThreadID)`. If you really want to do that, you have to manually store all threads in some collection and use that to find the thread and then call `Abort()` on that.

Comment: I think i need to abort the thread after i kicked a user because the Thread will wait and wait and wait for new data... i don't know how i can check the time in a console-application... or how would you check if there is no more connection at the TCPListener?

Comment: @Milian, you can call `Stop()` on the `TcpListener` from another thread. If you have a blocking `Accpet…()` call, it will throw `SocketException`. Doing this is much better than aborting the thread.